# В package.json автоматически не добавляются устанавливаемые пакеты Php Storm

Tags: phpstorm, npm

В package.json автоматически не добавляются устанавливаемые пакеты. Php Storm
Npm -v : 2.15.5
Устанавливаю пакет с флагами --save и --save-dev, командная строка от имени администратора, пытался выполнить через терминал node. Надежды тщетны все. В package не попадает ничего.

```html
C:\Users\Dmitry\Desktop\teplo>npm install gulp-sass -g --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
-
> node-sass@3.7.0 install C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node

> node-sass@3.7.0 postinstall C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node" exists.
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
gulp-sass@2.3.1 C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-sass
├── object-assign@4.1.0
├── through2@2.0.1 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@2.0.6)
├── vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.2.1 (source-map@0.5.6)
├── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, object-assign@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, beeper@1.1.0, repl
ace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, minimist@1.2.0, fancy-log@1.2.0, vinyl@0.5.3, gulplog@1.0.0, chalk@1.1.3, lodash.template@3.6.2, multipipe@0.1.2, dateformat@1.0.12)
└── node-sass@3.7.0 (get-stdin@4.0.1, async-foreach@0.1.3, in-publish@2.0.0, chalk@1.1.3, nan@2.3.3, mkdirp@0.5.1, glob@7.0.3, cross-spawn-async@2.2.4, meow@3.7.0, gaze@1.0.0, r
equest@2.72.0, sass-graph@2.1.1, node-gyp@3.3.1)
```

Comment: Операционная система Windows 10

Comment: для уверенности скопируйте в ваш пост строку с командой полностью

Comment: По указанной вами информации package.json должен был обновиться. Покажите логи после команды `npm i --save <пакет>`.

Comment: что значит команда полностью? npm install (пакет) -g --save-dev?)

Comment: Т.е. вы ставите пакеты глобально?

Comment: Да, я ставлю пакет глобально, не должен?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишете, что нужно ставить глобально. Уберите флаг `-g` и все будет записываться. Пример:

```
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev или кратко pm i gulp-sass -D
```